# Issue with default selected option of a select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using [knockout options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) and [select2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) on a select list. Initially i do not want to select any option by default instead i want to show a text something like 'Select country..' and this text should be selected initially. For this i used knockout `optionsCaption binding`. It works fine, but if i apply select2 plugin on the select list the initial default text is not selected. Here my code:

**HTML**

```
<select data-bind="options: array, optionsCaption: 'All'" size="1">
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('select').select2();

function VM(){
  this.array = 
    ['Afghanostan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Argentina']; 
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

I have created a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsbin.com/ivetel/2/edit) also.

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: "ALL"
});


<select data-bind="options: array" size="1" style="width: 200px;">
    <option><option>
</select>
```

See this link http://jsbin.com/ivetel/19/edit

Comment: It doesn't have the same "selected" look so I still don't think this answer is correct.  It may be acceptable for the poster's situation, but I think it's at least worth stating that it has a "placeholder"/greyed out look to it.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that "All" has a value of "".  From select2's source:

```
    initSelection: function () {
        var selected;
        if (this.opts.element.val() === "") {
            this.close();
            this.setPlaceholder();
        } else {
            var self = this;
            this.opts.initSelection.call(null, this.opts.element, function(selected){
                if (selected !== undefined && selected !== null) {
                    self.updateSelection(selected);
                    self.close();
                    self.setPlaceholder();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it shortcircuits if element.val() === ''.  You would need to modify the source of select2 to work with an empty-value option.